# Jest - Understanding execution order of a describe() and it()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to understand why all the blocks `describe()` run before the `it()` in inside of each `describe()`.

Here's a [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jestorderlogs-j4m6f) with a log per each `describe` and `it` block.

```js
describe("sum A", () => {
  window.innerWidth = 100;
  console.log("describe A", window.innerWidth);

  beforeAll(() => {
    window.innerWidth = 105;
    console.log("describe A before", window.innerWidth);
  });

  it("1. should add 1 and 2", () => {
    console.log("it A1", window.innerWidth);
    expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
  });
});

describe("sum B", () => {
  console.log("describe B", window.innerWidth, "why does it run before it A1?");

  beforeAll(() => {
    window.innerWidth = 205;
    console.log("describe B before", window.innerWidth);
  });

  it("1. should add 1 and 2", () => {
    console.log("it B1", window.innerWidth);
    expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

You'll notice that the log from the second describe block runs before the `it()` inside the first describe block.

Why does that happen? Should we avoid doing stuff in that part of the code and prefer using `beforeAll()` when we need to share and scope data in that describe block?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When `Jest` runs it looks for all of the test files and runs each one.

Each test file runs within an environment provided by `Jest` that includes globals like `describe`, `it`, `beforeAll`, etc.  All of these globals have a callback parameter that defines their behavior.

When a test file runs the top-level code runs...including any top-level `describe` calls.

When a `describe` runs it [registers a test suite](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/74f6faf2c87e8afaf56486378590e52c0089ef5a/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Env.ts#L369), and then [its callback is called immediately](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/74f6faf2c87e8afaf56486378590e52c0089ef5a/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Env.ts#L390).

This is different than `it`, `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`, etc. where [the callback is recorded but not immediately called](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/74f6faf2c87e8afaf56486378590e52c0089ef5a/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Env.ts#L576).

This means that all `describe` callback functions are called depth-first in the order they appear in a test file, as can be seen in this simple example:

```
describe('1', () => {
  console.log('1');
  describe('2', () => { console.log('2'); });
  describe('3', () => {
    console.log('3');
    describe('4', () => { console.log('4'); })
    describe('5', () => { console.log('5'); })
  })
  describe('6', () => { console.log('6'); })
})
describe('7', () => {
  console.log('7');
  it('(since there has to be at least one test)', () => { });
})
```

...which logs `1` - `7` in order.

This initial run of all the `describe` callbacks is called the [**collection phase**](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks) during which the test suites are defined and all of the callbacks for any `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`, `it`, `test`, etc. are collected.

After the collection phase completes, `Jest`...

> runs all the tests serially in the order they were encountered in the collection phase, waiting for each to finish and be tidied up before moving on.

For each test (each callback function registered with the global `it` or `test` functions) `Jest` [links together any before callbacks, the test callback itself, and any after callbacks](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/74f6faf2c87e8afaf56486378590e52c0089ef5a/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Spec.ts#L190) and runs the resulting functions in order.

---

> Should we avoid doing stuff in that part of the code and prefer using `beforeAll()` when we need to share and scope data in that describe block?

For simple stuff that isn't shared it's fine to have it in the `describe`:

```
describe('val', () => {
  const val = '1';

  it('should be 1', () => {
    expect(val).toBe('1');  // Success!
  });
});
```

...but code in the `describe` can cause issues with shared data:

```
describe('val', () => {
  let val;

  describe('1', () => {
    val = '1';
    it('should be 1', () => {
      expect(val).toBe('1');  // FAIL! (val gets set to 2 in the second describe)
    })
  })

  describe('2', () => {
    val = '2';
    it('should be 2', () => {
      expect(val).toBe('2');  // Success!
    })
  })

});
```

...which can be fixed either by using `before` calls:

```
describe('val', () => {
  let val;

  describe('1', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      val = '1';
    });
    it('should be 1', () => {
      expect(val).toBe('1');  // Success!
    })
  })

  describe('2', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      val = '2';
    });
    it('should be 2', () => {
      expect(val).toBe('2');  // Success!
    })
  })

});
```

...or simply scoping the data to the `describe`:

```
describe('val', () => {

  describe('1', () => {
    const val = '1';
    it('should be 1', () => {
      expect(val).toBe('1');  // Success!
    })
  })

  describe('2', () => {
    const val = '2';
    it('should be 2', () => {
      expect(val).toBe('2');  // Success!
    })
  })

});
```

In your example you are using `window.innerWidth` which is a shared global, so you will want to use `before` functions since it can't be scoped to the `describe`.

---

Also note that you [can't return anything from a `describe`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/74f6faf2c87e8afaf56486378590e52c0089ef5a/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Env.ts#L428-L454) so if your tests require any asynchronous setup then you will need to use a `before` function where you can return a `Promise` for `Jest` to await:

```
const somethingAsync = () => Promise.resolve('1');

describe('val', () => {
  let val;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    val = await somethingAsync();
  });

  it('should be 1', () => {
    expect(val).toBe('1');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer and exactly describes the problem I'm having. However, what I'm trying to accomplish is doing running some commands in `beforeEach` that run for multiple tests with the only difference being a single variable. I was hoping to set that variable in the `describe` block and have it get picked up in the parent `beforeEach` block. Is that possible? For context, it's logging in with an invalid password and with a valid password. Same steps, just a different password is being used. Thanks!